# How to get the last 'N' business days in a Unix shell script using a `for` loop?

Tags: linux, shell-script, date

The following script:

```
N=5
BUSINESS_DATE=`date -d "-2 day" +"%Y%m%d"`
for (( c=0; c<N ; c++ ))
do
    WEEKDAY=`date --date="$BUSINESS_DATE -$c day" +%w`

    if [ $WEEKDAY == "0" ]
    then
        FILE_DT_TMP=`date --date="$BUSINESS_DATE -$c day-2day" +%Y%m%d`;
    elif [ $WEEKDAY == "6" ]
    then
        FILE_DT_TMP=`date --date="$BUSINESS_DATE -$c day -2day" +%Y%m%d`;
    elif [ $WEEKDAY == "5" ]
    then
        FILE_DT_TMP=`date --date="$BUSINESS_DATE -$c day -2day" +%Y%m%d`;
    elif [ $WEEKDAY == "4" ]
    then
        FILE_DT_TMP=`date --date="$BUSINESS_DATE -$c day -2day" +%Y%m%d`;
    elif [ $WEEKDAY == "3" ]
    then
        FILE_DT_TMP=`date --date="$BUSINESS_DATE -$c day -2day" +%Y%m%d`;
    elif [ $WEEKDAY == "2" ]
    then
        FILE_DT_TMP=`date --date="$BUSINESS_DATE -$c day -2day" +%Y%m%d`;
    elif [ $WEEKDAY == "1" ]
    then
        FILE_DT_TMP=`date --date="$BUSINESS_DATE -$c day -2day" +%Y%m%d`;
    else
        FILE_DT_TMP=`date --date="$BUSINESS_DATE -$c day" +%Y%m%d`
    fi
    export FILE_DT=$FILE_DT_TMP
    echo "File date is :$FILE_DT"
done
```

is not giving proper output. 
Can anyone advise me – what’s wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: (0) Format your code so it’s readable.  (garethTheRed and I did that for you, including correcting the spelling of “business”.)  (1) Explain what you want it to do, in the body of the question.  (2) Say what it *is* doing.  (3) Describe what you have done to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: `for d in Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri ; do date +%Y%m%d -d "last $d" ; done | sort` is not acceptable?

Comment: this doesn't answer your question buy see also the `cal` command for a nicely formatted printout of the current month (or, with options, several months, or year).

Answer (score 2):

If you want just 5 working days before today try:

```
for d in Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri
do
    date +%Y%m%d -d "last $d"
done | sort
```

For any N-days before today:

```
N=10
for i in $(seq $(($N + $N / 5 * 2)) -1 1)
do
    [ `date --date="-$i day" +%u` -le 5 ] &&
       date -d "-$i day" +"File date is : %Y%m%d"
done
```

Comment: Sorry I want "N" business days not just 5.

Comment: @srikanth please [edit your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/240937/edit) to include this new information. Otherwise we aren't going to know, because the title of your post clearly states FIVE days, and your example code also uses a hard-coded 5.

Comment: @srikanth See updated

Answer (score 2):

I understand you actually want N days listed rather than the hardcoded five you have shown in your question. Here is a `bash` solution that will address this requirement:

```
n=5
today=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')
for ((d=1; n>0; d++))
do
    # Adjust this next line to get the date format you require, e.g. +'%Y%m%d'
    date=$(date --date "$today -$d day")
    nday=$(date --date "$today -$d day" +'%w')
    if [[ nday > 0 && nday < 6 ]]
    then
        # Adjust this next line to output whatever you really need
        echo "n=$n, d=$d, nday=$nday, date=$date: WEEKDAY"
        ((n--))
    fi
done
```

Output for `n=5`, run on 5th November 2015

```
n=5, d=1, nday=3, date=Wed,  4 Nov 2015 00:00:00: WEEKDAY
n=4, d=2, nday=2, date=Tue,  3 Nov 2015 00:00:00: WEEKDAY
n=3, d=3, nday=1, date=Mon,  2 Nov 2015 00:00:00: WEEKDAY
n=2, d=6, nday=5, date=Fri, 30 Oct 2015 00:00:00: WEEKDAY
n=1, d=7, nday=4, date=Thu, 29 Oct 2015 00:00:00: WEEKDAY
```

Answer (score 0):

When I apply these changes to your script:

```
1c1
< BUSSINESS_DATE=date -d "-2 day" +"%Y%m%d"
---
> BUSSINESS_DATE=$(date -d "-2 day" +"%Y%m%d")
5c5
<     WEEKDAY=date --date="$BUSSINESS_DATE -$c day" +%w
---
>     WEEKDAY=$(date --date="$BUSSINESS_DATE -$c day" +%w)
```

I get this output:

```
File date is :20151101
File date is :20151031
File date is :20151030
File date is :20151029
File date is :20151028
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: No. i gave that as an example.. i what to get last 5 business days from today.i.e., Excluding Saturday and sunday.For example for today i.e., 20151105 i want to get output as 20151104,20151103,20151102,20151030,20151029

Comment: OK. Thanks.  As you can see your example did not work before I made the above changes.  It's a little confusing when the example doesn't work.

Comment: Try to get required output na

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's extraordinarily unreadable.  Try using a case staement instead of if/then/elif/else/fi.

e.g.

```sh
BUSSINESS_DATE=$(date -d "-2 day" +"%Y%m%d")
for (( c=0; c<5 ; c++ )) ; do
    WEEKDAY=$(date --date="$BUSSINESS_DATE -$c day" +%w)

    case "$WEEKDAY" in
        0) FILE_DT_TMP=$(date --date="$BUSSINESS_DATE -$c day-2day" +%Y%m%d) ;;
        6) FILE_DT_TMP=$(date --date="$BUSSINESS_DATE -$c day -2day" +%Y%m%d) ;;
        5) FILE_DT_TMP=$(date --date="$BUSSINESS_DATE -$c day -2day" +%Y%m%d) ;;
        4) FILE_DT_TMP=$(date --date="$BUSSINESS_DATE -$c day -2day" +%Y%m%d) ;;
        3) FILE_DT_TMP=$(date --date="$BUSSINESS_DATE -$c day -2day" +%Y%m%d) ;;
        2) FILE_DT_TMP=$(date --date="$BUSSINESS_DATE -$c day -2day" +%Y%m%d) ;;
        1) FILE_DT_TMP=$(date --date="$BUSSINESS_DATE -$c day -2day" +%Y%m%d) ;;
        *) FILE_DT_TMP=$(date --date="$BUSSINESS_DATE -$c day" +%Y%m%d) ;;
    esac    

    export FILE_DT=$FILE_DT_TMP
    echo "File date is :$FILE_DT"
done
```

Note that reformatting it to make it more readable also makes it really obvious that there's a missing space between `day` and `-2day` on the `0` case.  easily fixed.

```
    0) FILE_DT_TMP=$(date --date="$BUSSINESS_DATE -$c day-2 day" +%Y%m%d) ;;
```

BTW, if I were you, I'd make the variable names much shorter (and maybe add a comment before the first use of them to clearly state what they are) to make the script even more readable, by avoiding line-wrapping.

e.g. change BUSINESS_DATE to BD

```
# BD is Business Date
BD=$(date -d "-2 day" +"%Y%m%d")
```

`FILE_DT_TMP` could be renamed to `FDT`, and `FILE_DT` to `FD` or `FDATE`.

```
BD=$(date -d "-2 day" +"%Y%m%d")
for (( c=0; c<5 ; c++ )) ; do
    WEEKDAY=$(date --date="$BD -$c day" +%w)

    case "$WEEKDAY" in
        0) FDT=$(date --date="$BD -$c day -2day" +%Y%m%d) ;;
        6) FDT=$(date --date="$BD -$c day -2day" +%Y%m%d) ;;
        5) FDT=$(date --date="$BD -$c day -2day" +%Y%m%d) ;;
        4) FDT=$(date --date="$BD -$c day -2day" +%Y%m%d) ;;
        3) FDT=$(date --date="$BD -$c day -2day" +%Y%m%d) ;;
        2) FDT=$(date --date="$BD -$c day -2day" +%Y%m%d) ;;
        1) FDT=$(date --date="$BD -$c day -2day" +%Y%m%d) ;;
        *) FDT=$(date --date="$BD -$c day" +%Y%m%d) ;;
    esac    

    FDATE="$FDT"
    echo "File date is : $FDATE""
done
```

There's a real advantage to reformatting code like this - when things that are supposed to line up don't line up, they stand out like a flashing neon sign.

Other notes:

1. I've changed all the backticks to `$()`.  backticks are obsolete and mess up quoting, don't use them.
2. There's no need to export FILE_DT (aka FDATE) - the variable will be lost when the sub-shell it's being run in terminates.  It will only be set in the parent shell if you source the script with `. scriptname`.

Comment: Thanks for the formating. i was in a hurrey so could nt do it that way.. Stil i  did not get the required output.I want last "n" business days.

Comment: @srikanth was the problem caused by the missing space between `day` and `-2day` for the `0` case that i pointed out?  edit your question to show an example of the ouput you are getting and an example of the output you expect to get.